# Why does "Community" edit answers?

Tags: discussion

What happened here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/posts/7298/revisions (rev 2, by "Community")?

Comment: I was super confused!

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing.

It was [an edit suggestion by an anonymous user](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/207), the edit was a major one and I didn't know enough about the topic to know if it is OK so I didn't approve it.

It seems that when such an edit suggestion is approved it is shown as an edit by community user.

Comment: I did the approval, since it seemed reasonable to me (seemed mostly rephrasing rather than technical). It is odd that this is attributed to community though

Comment: @Suresh is there a way to be notified of these changes (since it was to my answer) when they are suggested? I have come across the edit(1) button occasionally on questions and approved them, but I don't think this one notified me.

Comment: Not sure. I don't know how that works.

Comment: @Artem, they show up in [your responses page](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/1037/artem-kaznatcheev?tab=responses&page=1&rfilter=revisions).

Comment: @Kaveh maybe it was because I was offline when Suresh approved the changes, but only the 'changes approved' thing appears in my responses, not the changes suggested. I guess this is what I get for sleeping, haha.

Comment: @Artem, you can post a a future request that suggested edits should also show up in the post owner's inbox but I personally would not like it because that would be too many notifications. I think the current situation is better, if you don't like an edit to your post you can easily role it back.